# Dimensionality reduction with locality-sensitive hashing

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, locality-sensitive-hash

I have a conceptual understanding of locality-sensitive hashing (LSH) in relation to near-neighbour search. However, the articles that I have read so far seem to gloss over the details of how LSH can be used for probabilistic dimensionality reduction (e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing)).

**Questions**

1. How does LSH reduce the dimensionality of data?
2. Can I specify the dimensionality of the subspace or is this predetermined?